# Import data from mysql to BigQuery using Data Fusion

Tags: sql, ssh, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to connect from Data Fusion to mysql, but I can't find any preferences to connect via SSH. Where I Can find it or may be DF doesn't support this method of connection?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

There's no option within the Data Fusion connector to use SSH. Depending on your setup, you would either need to set up an SSH tunnel or configure a VPC to connect to your MySql instance.